# SharePoint Online 'Filter By' not showing all available options

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter

I have created a custom list which contains around 32,000 items. There is a 4 part key which looks something like 'T1-0000-X-XX'. Each part has a meaning. In order for users to be able to filter by each of the parts, I separated this key into 4 separate columns and indexed each column. Call them Key1, Key2, Key3, Key4. When a user tries to filter on Key1, it does not show all the values that exist in the list. They start typing and the one they are looking for does not show up. Therefore, SharePoint does not allow them to use that value to filter. I know the value exists and if I choose another value and then change the URL so it filters on the value I actually want, the filter works. So it is there. But no matter what I have tried, I cannot get the value I want from the UI. I have not yet tried recreating this field yet, which might be my next option. But repopulating it might be a hassle.
As you can see in the image, T2 is clearly available in the Group field. But cannot be found by the filter.

[image]

Comment: I decided to Create a new field, gave it a different name. Ran a PowerShell to copy all the values from the first column into this new column. All ran fine, but at the end of the whole thing, the same result!! And it is ONLY for the T2 value. Every other unique value in the list for that field shows up in the filter. Except T2. Is there something special about a T2 code maybe? Something hard coded in SharePoint somewhere that doesn't allow T2??
I might believe that, except that this same filter works fine in another list with similar data, same fields and I can filter on 'T2'.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that no more than 5000 items are displayed in a list view.

List settings> Advanced settings>Reindex List then compare the result.

[image]

In addition, use the list filter panel to check if the value can be filtered using "T2":

[image]